# How to make a one2many field on a view query 2 or more fields at related table

Tags: odoo, odoo-12, qweb

I want the field `partner_id` at view `project.task.form.quick_create` to query both `res.partner.name` and `res.partner.company_name`.

- filter_domain does not work;
- domain only works with fixed values;

Here is the view `project.task.form.quick_create`:

```
<form>
    <group>
        <field name="name" string="Task Title"/>
        <field name="partner_id" options="{'no_quick_create': True, 'no_create_edit' : True}" 
          filter_domain="['|', ('company_name','ilike',self),('name','ilike',self)]"/>
        <field name="user_id" options="{'no_open': True,'no_create': True}" eval="False" />
    </group>
</form>
```

Comment: You need to override `name_search` for this kind a behavior, because its the method called by many2one field when you start typing

Comment: @CharifDZ thank you, its working. It's not what I expected to do, as its possible to change the behavior of the search field using filter_domain, then intuitively it should be possible to change the behavior of the many2one the same way. Sadly, its not the case.

Answer (score 1):

No, its not possible to do what you want to do the way you want to do it.
As @CharifDZ pointed out, you will have to override name_search.
Here is how you should do it

```py
class ResPartner(models.Model):
  _name = 'res.partner'
  _inherit = 'res.partner'

  @api.model
  def name_search(self, name, args=None, operator='ilike', limit=100):
    args = args or []
    if name:
       args += ['|', ('name', 'ilike', name), ('company_name', 'ilike', name)]
       name = ''
    return super(ResPartner, self).name_search(name=name, args=args, operator=operator, limit=limit)
```

Comment: And if you want this behavior only in one view you can pass a context in your one2many and that key will be passed when you search in your many2one field. So all you have to do is check the context, if the many2one is not in one2many you need to pass context key in the window action.